# Pyqt: How to change QGroupBox title color?

Tags: python, colors, pyqt, qgroupbox

I have a QGroupBox which objectName is "of_esq". How do I change the color of its title?

Is it something like: `self.of_esq.setStyleSheet("of_esq.title {color: green}")`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting the stylesheet directly on the `of_esq` widget, you could just do (assuming it has no child `QGroupBoxes`

```
self.of_esq.setStyleSheet('QGroupBox  {color: green;}')
```

You could also set the stylesheet on `of_esq`'s parent and reference the widget by name using the css id selector (`#`)

```
self.setStyleSheet('#of_esq {color: green;}')
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly it. Didn't figure out yet that `setStyleSheet`is basically CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but here's how I did this:

First, I created my UI in Qt Designer, which contained a QGroupBox. I spent an inordinate amount of time trying to find a color property within Qt Designer which would **ONLY** affect the QGroupBox title. Finally, I resorted to modifying the converted ui code (heeding the *"WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!"* given by the conversion utility)

Next, I located the code where the stylesheet was being set on the groupBox widget:

```
self.groupBox.setStyleSheet("")
```

Next, I modified this code, "drilling down" to the title to set the color:

```
self.groupBox.setStyleSheet('QGroupBox:title {color: rgb(1, 130, 153);}')
```

This seems to work on other widgets as well using Brendan Abel's first example. Just be sure you specifically specify the exact widget.

To verify, I added three radio buttons to my layout (within the QGroupBox). After saving, I regenerated the Python ui code. Then I modified just ONE of the radio buttons:

```
self.radioButton_2.setStyleSheet('QRadioButton {color: rgb(1, 130, 153);}')
```

This ONLY changed the text color of the radioButton_2 widget.

It would be MUCH more convenient having the widget color properties available in Qt Designer, but this seems to be a viable workaround. Just be aware that regenerating the ui code after making changes in Qt Designer will overwrite your modified code.